# C++ vector of lambdas - undefined references

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

I am trying to wrap several constructors in lambdas in order to store those in a vector and then loop over it:

```
using move_constructor = std::function<Move*(Site,vector<Move*>*, int)>;

vector<move_constructor> diff_plane_list = {
  [](Site p_site, vector<Move*>* move_list, int latLen) {
    return new Diffuse_inplane_px(p_site, move_list, latLen);
  },
  [](Site p_site, vector<Move*>* move_list, int latLen) {
    return new Diffuse_inplane_mx(p_site, move_list, latLen);
  },
  ...
}
```

However, when trying to compile it using g++-5.3, I get the following error message for each item in the vector:

```
/tmp/ccc2A87Z.o: In function `{lambda(std::tuple<int, int, int>, std::vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*, int)#1}::operator()(std::tuple<int, int, int>, std::vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*, int) const':
All_moves.cc:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `Diffuse_inplane_px::Diffuse_inplane_px(std::tuple<int, int, int>, std::vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*, int)'
```

So the `vector<Move*>*` gets somehow cast to `vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*`?
How should I do this properly? Is there a better way to loop over a list of constructors and store the pointers to the created objects in a vector?

Comment: *"undefined reference"*: You don't provide definition of specified `Diffuse_inplane_px` constructor.

Comment: BTW, it would be better to return `std::unique_ptr<Move>` instead of raw owning pointer. (and create your `make_unique` as you don't have C++14).

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

*"undefined reference"*: You don't provide definition of specified `Diffuse_inplane_px` constructor.

Provide one and make sure it is linked to the project.

Comment: Yes, gcc wants me to specify a constructor `Diffuse_inplane_px(std::tuple<int, int, int>, std::vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*, int)`, and I don't understand why the second argument has to be a `vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*> >*`, and not a `vector<Move*>*`. The argument to the lambda is of this type, and it's also specified in the definition of `move_constructor`. A constructor using this type for the second argument is specified in a different, linked file.

Comment: `std::vector` has default template argument, so `vector<Move*>` is same as `vector<Move*, std::allocator<Move*>>`. You just have to provide `Diffuse_inplane_px(Site, std::vector<Move*>*, int)`.